# Check if state array contains object id, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, filter

I'm developing an app which has to fetch new orders from the Firestore database, I used `componentDidMount` to refresh the screen every 10 seconds and launch the `fetchNewOrders` function, if new orders are available, the function should push that object into the state array `newOrder`, and display the orders in the FlatList below. When I start the code it returns the error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.id')`, I also wrote the example of an array I'm fetching from the database.

**Screen**

```
   export default class Received extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          loaded: false,
          newOrder: [],
        };
      }

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.updateTimer = setInterval(() => {
          this.fetchNewOrders();
          }, 10000);
      }
    
        fetchNewOrders = async () => {
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, path));
            if(querySnapshot.length !== 0) {
              querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                let array = this.state.newOrder;
                const data = doc.data().order;
                data.map(({obj, id}) => {
                  const filter = array.find(c => c.id === id);
                  if (filter == undefined) {
                    array.push(obj)
                    this.setState({ newOrder: array })
                  }
                })
              })
            }
          }

render() {

        return (
          <View>
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.newOrder}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
              renderItem={({ item }) => {
                return (
                  <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text>{item.serviceRequested}</Text>
                    <View>
                      <Tex>${item.total}</Text>
                    </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                )
              }}
            />
          </View>
        )
      }
}
```

**data (new order)**

```
Array [
  Object {
    "date": "Mon Feb 28 2022 11:24:14 GMT-0500 (EST)",
    "id": 0.9436716663143794,
    "instructions": "",
    "order": Array [
      /////////////
    ],
    "paymentType": "Cash",
    "serviceRequested": "Delivery",
    "total": 10.4,
  },
]
```

Comment: Are you aware that firestore allows WebSocket connections, thus eliminating the need to poll the database?

Comment: I think the problem is in loader and code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState is an async function that schedules a render with new state. It should only be called once per render, not in a loop.

```
    const append = [];

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

      const data = doc.data().order;

      // Is there bad data without ids?
      data.filter(c => c.id && !this.state.newOrder.some(no => no.id === c.id))
          .forEach((d) => append.push(d));
    });

    // Create the new state, then set it once.
    this.setState({ newOrder: [...this.state.newOrder, ...append]});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest filtering your data (this.state.newOrder) first. This would make it so that you only display items that have ids.

Suggested Change:

```
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.newOrder.filter((order)=>order.id)}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text>{item.serviceRequested}</Text>
                <View>
                  <Tex>${item.total}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )
          }}
        />
```

Above is code to fix this issue as described, but I would suggest that you make sure the Firestore only sends data that has id's if possible. Obviously, this may be out of your hands, but I would make sure that the Firestore is giving you reliable data, as it could cause more problems down the road.